# SQL Server 2005 - removing permission from a Windows Authentication login

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-authentication

How Can I remove permissions from a windows authentication login in SQL 2005.  Currently when I create a login in SQL Server 2005 and use the login in TSQL I can update/select/insert/delete all table in any database in the db server.  Creating low level permission(on database level) is not working either.